# iOS app throws error Thread 4: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0) with custom Tensorflow tflite model

Tags: ios, xcode, tensorflow

I created custom tflite model. Next downloaded the example from here:
https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/object_detection/ios

and replaced tflite file with mine. The app throws error like below, but still running and nothing detecting. How can I inspect what is wrong? What does it mean that "tensors were not allocated"? While I use original file from the example everything is working fine.

[image: screen]

Comment: Have you find the solution yet?

Comment: I face the same problem while running a different TFLite model for face recognition. It runs without a problem some time and then starts to give this error.

Comment: @DimaRostopira, Ozgur Sahin I posted right answer, input/output arrays must be the same as in an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Input/output arrays must be the same as in an example. Use some tool to explore default tflite model. This is result of my investigation. While converting .pb to .tflite try that arrays:

--input_arrays=normalized_input_image_tensor 
--output_arrays='TFLite_Detection_PostProcess','TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:1','TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:2','TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:3'